# What is meant by Low-Order combination of features?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, feature-selection, autoencoders, feature-engineering

I came across a Machine Learning paper that talks about input with **low-order combination of features**. A statement says:

> The initial feature is used as the input of the model, and the
>   non-linear feature of the initial feature is transformed to obtain the
>   first hidden layer, the low-order combination.

The model mentioned is a Stacked Autoencoder. What is meant by low-order combination?

Comment: It would be helpful if you referenced the paper in question. Usually a "low order [approximation]" refers to a *linear* way of approximating a *non-linear* effect, especially using splines. "Low order" here refers to few degrees of freedom: i.e. breakpoints and polynomial terms.

Comment: @AdamO, Well, you may find the paper [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/331104663_Research_on_CTR_prediction_based_on_stacked_autoencoder)

Comment: @AdamO, the above statement can be found in the section **3.3.3 BGAE model**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cited paper concerns detecting and testing *interactions* in a set of features. The general notion of an interaction concerns a derived term representing the product of two *or more* features. For instance the authors state:

> While in principle [Factorization machines] can model high-order feature interactions, in practice usually only order-2 feature interactions are considered
>   due to high complexity.

The modeling technique is irrelevant here. With just 8 terms there are 4-choose-2 = 28 possible two-way interactions (what the authors have, for convenience called "low order" interactions). Most "interaction detection" algorithms involve searching all possible two-way ($a \times b$) interactions before considering three-way or higher. Note in our 8 term example, the number of possible 3 way interactions is 8-choose-3 = 56, 4-ways: 70, and in all 210 possible interactions of 3 or more terms. It's natural to develop some "big data" techniques to detecting these interactions, since it is not a necessary or sufficient condition that, for a 3 level interaction to exist, some combination of 2 level interactions must be present

Comment: I understand your explanation. But this statement `The low-order combination of features as a new learning object and the combination features of the higher-order are obtained by non-linear transformation.` again confuses me.

Comment: @PSNayak technically the product of two variables is a non-linear transformation. That should form a basis for your understanding, no pun intended.

Comment: Thanks for your support.